# Reduce Multiple Errors logging in sysssislog

Tags: ssis

Need help. I am trying to automate error notifications to be sent in mailers. For that I am querying the sysssislog table. I have pasted an "Execute SQl task" on the package event handler "On error".  For testing purpose, I am deliberately trying to load duplicate keys in a table which consists of a Primary key column(so as to get an error).

But instead of having just one error, "Violation of primary key constraint", SSIS records 3 in the table. PFA the screenshot as well. How can i restrict the tool to log only one error and not multiple ???

Package Structure.

Package ("On error Event handler") - > DFT -> 
                 Oledb Source  - > Oledb Destination

```
 SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SalesPerson_SalesPersonID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SalesPerson'.".  
  SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (56)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (56)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  
  SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (43) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (56). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

Please guide me. Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following query.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.sysssislog
    WHERE sourceid IN (SELECT DISTINCT sourceid FROM dbo.sysssislog WHERE event = 'PackageStart')
```

Notice the sub-query inside the where clause? By doing this we'll only be selecting the rows having sourceids which appear in PackageStart events.  PackageStart events always have the top-level sourceids and never the subcomponent sourceids.  So, with the where clause in place, you are effectively filtering out all of the subcomponent or "multiple" error messages.  Take a look at the FirstError column of the query inside [this article](http://troywitthoeft.com/simple-ssis-package-monitoring-for-sql-server-2008/).

Comment: Thank you Troy . Though i had figured out a similar solution way back , but this also gives a new dimesnion.

Comment: Troy, the result of the query mentioned isn't correct. I cross verified with the logs. Please check before use.

Answer (score 0):

By design all the task level errors "bubble up" to the package level and hence you see the multiple errors. If you need only 1 error message, you will need to differentiate the source of the error i.e to say, where it is coming from. That can easily be done through the SourceName column (or in fact the TaskID). If you are using out of the box logging, these columns might not be available. Writing a custom logging script is not that tough though.